# GLMNET in R: Difference between DFMAX and PMAX

Tags: r, glmnet

In `glmnet` in R, what is the difference between `dfmax` and `pmax` when creating a model with both ridge and lasso penalties?

Is the following interpretation correct?

Let's say we have we run a `glmnet` elastic net with 500 predictors and we only want to include in 3 predictors in the final model; i.e. we want the lasso eliminate 497 predictors. In order to do so, do we set `dfmax = 500` and `pmax = 3`?

Comment: You only need `pmax=3`. The `dfmax` argument is to limit the extent of the forward search, eg if you had thousands of predictors and you knew in advance that you were only interested in modelling a hundred of them at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is actually pmax that limits the forward search. If pmax is set to a low number, a warning message about early termination of the lambda path is given.  I have noticed however, that if dfmax is used with cv.glmnet it behaves as expected, but not necessarily if used with vanilla glmnet. I think there may be a bug.